# C++ class or namespace?

Tags: c++, oop

I am a beginner in programing in c++ and I can't really imagine how to make an Object Oriented Design. Every time I apply classes, inheritance, polymorphism or function overloading, the code I make gets really messy and hard to keep track of things. I always think that "maybe I'm making too many things for the computer to handle", "is it really necessary to do it like this?"  or "I'm gonna make an array of this class, isn't putting functions and private variables here kind of stupid?" when thinking of an Object Oriented Design.

For example, when looking at tutorials in making a file loader(for shaders, meshes, mapping of tiled textures or many more), they usually put their functions and structs in classes and I think why are they putting it in a class instead of using a struct and namespace?

```
class fileLoader{
public:
fileLoader(const char* filePath);

struct fileContents{
glm::vec2 location;
//other data
}
//other funtions
}
```

vs

```
struct fileContents{
glm::vec2 location;
//other data
}

namespace FileLoader{
loadfile(const char* filepath);
//other funtions
}
```

Or making a simple rpg, they say that you should use classes, inheritance and function overloading in monsters, NPCs and characters but it's hard to follow through and (in my opinion) quite messy. Isn't it easier to make things like monsters, NPCs, chest and others as structs or a cluster of data that and goes through multiple functions in transforming their attributes?

I'm a beginner and have no formal education in programming so sorry if this things are common sense to seasoned programmers.

Comment: Rule of thumb: If you never instantiate the class and instead just call `static` functions, or the class doesn't have any real properties, it's just a "bag of functions", then it's just a namespace in disguise.

Comment: Your first paragraph makes it almost sound like you put everything in one source file, which does make things unnecessarily messy

Comment: You must be doing very strange things if you consider _"structs or a cluster of data"_ to be easier than classes with proper functions. But hey, I thought the same in my first few projects :D

Comment: There's little to no cost difference between a (non-virtual) member function and a free function so use whichever makes more sense in your code

Comment: I'm almost tempted to suggest that this be declared a wiki/faq, considering how it's going so far

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes i separate these functions and structs in headers. sorry if my paragraph is missleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when implementing a struct inside a class or writing a nested class (a class within a class) you want to achieve a principle called encapsulation, where you want that struct or class hidden or inaccessible by the user. Now to why we put or functions inside of a class or a struct conforms with the object oriented design, where you want each object to have a specific set of functionalities similar to that of a car. Surely, you can approach your code similar to the design you specified in your question but that doesn't go in harmony with the oop convention.

Comment: OOP is really hard for me to imagine, maybe because i always think what the code might look like in assembly :D. can you suggest a good tutorial for OOP?

Comment: You can start by searching for "Programming with mosh" on youtube. He has very elaborative videos on many programming concepts. Also check the cherno's C++ playlist it has many videos that will definitely help you out a lot